# How to remove a style

Tags: html, css

My current theme looks like this: https://gyazo.com/70ebe1ff52847bfbd7220f8e9bbe4854

But when i insert the bootstrap cdn I get: https://gyazo.com/1d97573cc6765ee55f99d99b5094f0cc

I check the css using chrome but I don't understand what changed when I got bootstrap. **My navbar got larger and has a black line under the navbar**. How can I know what's causing this and how can I remove it? Thank you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar bg-primary-gradient col-lg-12 col-12 p-0 fixed-top navbar-inverse d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="bg-white text-center navbar-brand-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo" href="#"><img src="images/logo_star_black.png"/></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand brand-logo-mini" href="#"><img src="images/logo_star_mini.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper d-flex align-items-center">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler hidden-md-down align-self-center mr-3" type="button"
                    data-toggle="minimize">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 hidden-md-down">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto d-flex align-items-center flex-row">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link profile-pic" href="#"><img class="rounded-circle" src="images/face.jpg"
                                                                  alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up align-self-center" type="button"
                    data-toggle="offcanvas">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End navbar-->
```

Comment: adding bootstrap means adding a lot of CSS, so it's logic your site get a bit scrambled, you need to adjust YOUR CSS accordingly

Comment: I understand that but how can I know what caused this? Surely there must be a property that gave navbar a bigger height and a black line. Do you know what those properties are?

Comment: u have to find them by using some inspect element

Comment: as Arvind said, you need to inspect element and see what CSS is added to your nav

Answer (score 0):

Add css

```
.navbar-inverse
{
 border: none !Important;
}
```